# Deleting specific item from array, not working as intended

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, firebase, react-native

can someone tell me what is the problem with deleting an item from the array? In deleteSingleItemHandler with axios.delete method it works like it should and on firebase deletes exactly the selected item but when i want to remove item from state array, it removes an item but not the exactly selected one, example, i click on the third item, on firebase it deletes the third item and it removes second on my devices screen... What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!
Cheers

```
class HistoryScreen extends Component {
  state = {
    orders: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get(".../orders.json")
      .then(response => {
        const fetchedOrders = [];

        for (let key in response.data) {
          fetchedOrders.push({
            ...response.data[key],
            id: key
          });
        }

        this.setState({ orders: fetchedOrders });

      });
  }

  deleteSingleItemHandler = id => {
    axios
      .delete(`...orders/${id}.json`)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
      });

    const newArray = [...this.state.orders];
    newArray.splice(id, 1);

    this.setState({ orders: newArray });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView>
          <View style={styles.completeOrder}>

              {this.state.orders.map(order => {
              return (
                <TouchableOpacity
                  key={order.id}
                  onPress={() => this.deleteSingleItemHandler(order.id)}
                >
                  <View style={styles.singleItem}>
                    <View style={styles.orderItem}>
                      <View style={{ flex: 1, marginLeft: 5 }}>
                        <Text style={{ fontFamily: Fonts.GloriaHallelujah }}>
                          {order.articleName}
                        </Text>
                      </View>

                      <View
                        style={{
                          flex: 1,
                          justifyContent: "flex-end",
                          flexDirection: "row",
                          marginRight: 5
                        }}
                      >
                        <Text>{order.articlePrice}</Text>
                      </View>
                    </View>
                  </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              );
            })}
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first param of the function [`Array.prototype.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) is an index.

*Use the function [`Array.prototype.findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)*

```
newArray.splice(newArray.findIndex(o => o.id === id), 1);
```

*Or you can filter that object using the function [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)*

```
newArray = newArray.filter(o => o.id !== id);
```